# How to play multiple video files simultaneously in one layout side by side in different view in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, surfaceview, android-videoview, android-mediaplayer

In Android, I created a layout with three surface view side by side, and I want to play one video file with different media player simultaneously. But one problem I faced that none of three can play that video simultaneously. One or two of them getting stopped the display.
If I used video view instead of Media Player class directly, but the problem remains the same.
Please anybody can help. What the problem is for? It is giving error surface creation failed native error. I tried different combination such as one file in 3 different view, three files in three different view, but the problem is not fixed yet.
Some replies in other web site says that it depends on kernel version.
If it depends on Kernel version, please can you give me any android documentation link on android site that it depends on kernel version. Or it is possible to play, please give me the steps of code. This is error log -

```
04-10 19:23:37.995: E/ANDROID_DRM_TEST(2573): Client::notify In
04-10 19:23:37.995: V/AudioPolicyManager(2573): startOutput() output 1, stream 3,  session 131
04-10 19:23:37.995: V/AudioPolicyManager(2573): getDeviceForStrategy() from cache strategy 0, device 2
04-10 19:23:37.995: V/AudioPolicyManager(2573): getNewDevice() selected device 2
04-10 19:23:37.995: V/AudioPolicyManager(2573): setOutputDevice() output 1 device 2 delayMs 0
04-10 19:23:37.995: V/AudioPolicyManager(2573): setOutputDevice() setting same device 2 or null device for output 1
04-10 19:23:37.995: I/AudioFlinger(2573): start output streamType (0, 3) for 1
04-10 19:23:37.995: D/AudioHardwareYamaha(2573): AudioStreamOut::setParameters(keyValuePairs="start_output_streamtype=3")
04-10 19:23:38.010: W/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_setPosition(0) 0,0,200,397 => 0,0,200,397
04-10 19:23:38.010: I/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_setParameter param[4]=4
04-10 19:23:38.010: D/SEC_Overlay(2689): dst width, height have changed [w= 200, h= 397] -> [w=200, h= 397]
04-10 19:23:38.010: I/SEC_Overlay(2689): Nothing to do!
04-10 19:23:38.090: E/VideoMIO(2573): AndroidSurfaceOutput::setParametersSync()  VIDEO ROTATION 0
04-10 19:23:38.090: E/VideoMIO(2573): AndroidSurfaceOutput::setParametersSync()  VIDEO RENDERER 1
04-10 19:23:38.090: D/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=128 h=96 format=48
04-10 19:23:38.090: E/SEC_Overlay(2689): Error - overlays already in use
04-10 19:23:38.090: D/VideoMIO(2573): Overlay create failed - retrying
04-10 19:23:38.195: D/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=128 h=96 format=48
04-10 19:23:38.195: E/SEC_Overlay(2689): Error - overlays already in use
04-10 19:23:38.195: D/VideoMIO(2573): Overlay create failed - retrying
04-10 19:23:38.230: E/VideoMIO(2573): AndroidSurfaceOutput::setParametersSync()  VIDEO ROTATION 0
04-10 19:23:38.230: E/VideoMIO(2573): AndroidSurfaceOutput::setParametersSync()  VIDEO RENDERER 1
04-10 19:23:38.230: D/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=128 h=96 format=48
04-10 19:23:38.230: E/SEC_Overlay(2689): Error - overlays already in use
04-10 19:23:38.230: D/VideoMIO(2573): Overlay create failed - retrying
04-10 19:23:38.295: D/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=128 h=96 format=48
04-10 19:23:38.295: E/SEC_Overlay(2689): Error - overlays already in use
04-10 19:23:38.295: D/VideoMIO(2573): Overlay create failed - retrying
04-10 19:23:38.330: D/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=128 h=96 format=48
04-10 19:23:38.330: E/SEC_Overlay(2689): Error - overlays already in use
04-10 19:23:38.330: D/VideoMIO(2573): Overlay create failed - retrying
04-10 19:23:38.395: D/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=128 h=96 format=48
04-10 19:23:38.395: E/SEC_Overlay(2689): Error - overlays already in use
04-10 19:23:38.395: D/VideoMIO(2573): Overlay create failed - retrying
04-10 19:23:38.435: D/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=128 h=96 format=48
04-10 19:23:38.435: E/SEC_Overlay(2689): Error - overlays already in use
04-10 19:23:38.435: D/VideoMIO(2573): Overlay create failed - retrying
04-10 19:23:38.495: D/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=128 h=96 format=48
04-10 19:23:38.495: E/SEC_Overlay(2689): Error - overlays already in use
04-10 19:23:38.495: D/VideoMIO(2573): Overlay create failed - retrying
04-10 19:23:38.535: D/SEC_Overlay(2689): overlay_createOverlay:IN w=128 h=96 format=48
```

Comment: What makes you think that this is possible at all?

Comment: If it is possible how and give me some code step. If it is not possible why and give reason. Because I can't play all file simultaneously. Only one video can play smoothly.

Comment: please provide code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one solution. Just replace /system/build.prop with this following build.prop -

build.prop

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=GINGERBREAD
ro.build.display.id=GINGERBREAD.EG14
ro.build.version.incremental=EG14
ro.build.version.sdk=10
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.release=2.3.4
ro.build.date=Thu Jul 14 12:16:01 KST 2011
ro.build.date.utc=1310613361
ro.build.type=user
ro.build.user=se.infra
ro.build.host=SEI-28
ro.build.tags=release-keys
ro.product.model=SHW-M250S
ro.product.brand=samsung
ro.product.name=SHW-M250S
ro.product.device=SHW-M250S
ro.product.board=SHW-M250S
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
# Samsung Specific Properties
ro.build.PDA=M250S.EG14.1208
ro.build.hidden_ver=M250S.EG14.1208
ro.b uild.changelist=380592
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=samsung
ro.product.locale.language=ko
ro.product.locale.region=KR
ro.wifi.channels=
ro.board.platform=s5pc210
# ro.build.product is obsolete; use ro.product.device
ro.build.product=SHW-M250S
# Do not try to parse ro.build.description or .fingerprint
ro.build.description=SHW-M250S-user 2.3.4 GINGERBREAD EG14 release-keys
ro.build.fingerprint=samsung/SHW-M250S/SHW-M250S:2.3.4/GINGERBREAD/EG14:user/release-keys
# Samsung Specific Properties
ro.build.PDA=M250S.EG14.1208
ro.build.hidden_ver=M250S.EG14.1208
ro.build.changelist=380592
ro.build.fota_ver=SSNT11GINGEREG14
ro.tether.denied=false
ro.flash.resolution=1080
# end build properties
#
# system.prop for asop5000
#

rild.libpath=/system/lib/libsec-ril.so
rild.libargs=-d /dev/ttyS0
ro.sf.lcd_density=240
dalvik.vm.heapsize=64m

# Samsung USB default mode
persist.service.usb.setting=2

#
# ADDITIONAL_BUILD_PROPERTIES
#
ro.setupwizard.mode=OPTIONAL
ro.com.google.gmsversion=2.3_r4
media.stagefright.enable-player=true
media.stagefright.enable-meta=true
media.stagefright.enable-scan=true
media.stagefright.enable-http=true
media.stagefright.enable-rtsp=true
ro.com.google.clientidbase=android-samsung
ro.com.google.clientidbase.ms=android-skt-kr
ro.com.google.clientidbase.am=android-skt-kr
ro.com.google.clientidbase.gmm=android-samsung
ro.com.google.clientidbase.yt=android-samsung
ro.url.legal=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html
ro.url.legal.android_privacy=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/privacy.html
ro.com.google.locationfeatures=1
keyguard.no_require_sim=true
ro.config.ringtone=Over_the_horizon.ogg
ro.config.notification_sound=Sherbet.ogg
ro.config.alarm_alert=Good_Morning.ogg
ro.config.media_sound=Over_the_horizon.ogg
ro.opengles.version=131072
ro.csc.sales_code=MSK
ro.secdevenc=true
ro.wtldatapassword=true
net.bt.name=Android
dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file=/data/anr/traces.txt
```

At first connect your Samsung Galaxy s-II with usb and type in command prompt to mount your system -

```
cmd:> adb remount
```

and then replace the file and reboot your device -

```
cmd:> adb shell
#reboot
```

I've noticed that by default this device uses opencore framework instead of libstagefright. And opencore has some problem, that's why the nave error is throwing. But libstagefright is already implemented in android version 2.3. Have a look at the build.prop file, the stagefright is disable. It is the best solution to enable to libstagefright framework and do support libstagefright framework. You can play MPEG-2TS file also and it supports to play multiple video file simultaneously without having any problem. 
Try it and enjoy.

Comment: This solution is for only rooted device. what about the non-rooted devices?

Answer (score 36):

You are not giving an awful lot of specifics on what exactly you have tried and what the problematic areas are, so I just made a small test to see if I could reproduce any of what you're describing.

I do not have any conclusive findings, but can at least confirm that my Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.0.2) is able to play three videos simultaneously without any problems. On the other hand, an old Samsung Galaxy Spica (Android 2.1-update1) I had lying around only plays a single  file at a time - it appears to always be the first `SurfaceView`.

I further investigated different API levels by setting up emulators for Android 3.0, 2.3.3, and 2.2. All these platforms appear to be able to handle playback of multiple video files onto different surface views just fine. I did one final test with an emulator running 2.1-update1 too, which interestingly also played the test case without problems, unlike the actual phone. I did notice some slight differences in how the layout was rendered though.

This behaviour leads me to suspect that there's not really any software limitation to what you're after, but it seems to depend on the hardware wether simultaneous playback of multiple video files is supported. Hence the support for this scenario will differ per device. From an emperical point of view, I definitely think it would be interesting to test this hypotheses on some more physical devices.

Just for reference some details with regards to the implementation:

1. I set up two slightly different implementations: one based on three `MediaPlayer` instances in a single `Activity`, and one in which these were factored out into three separate fragments with each their own `MediaPlayer` object. (I did not find any playback differences for these two implementations by the way)
2. A single [3gp file](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425) (thanks for that, Apple), located in the `assets` folder, was used for playback with all players.
3. The code for both implementations is attached below and largely based on Googles [`MediaPlayerDemo_Video`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html) sample implementation - I did strip away some code not required for the actual testing. The result is by no means complete or suitable for using in live apps.

---

**Activity-based implementation:**

```
public class MultipleVideoPlayActivity extends Activity implements
    OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayer";
    private static final int[] SURFACE_RES_IDS = { R.id.video_1_surfaceview, R.id.video_2_surfaceview, R.id.video_3_surfaceview };

    private MediaPlayer[] mMediaPlayers = new MediaPlayer[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
    private SurfaceView[] mSurfaceViews = new SurfaceView[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
    private SurfaceHolder[] mSurfaceHolders = new SurfaceHolder[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
    private boolean[] mSizeKnown = new boolean[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];
    private boolean[] mVideoReady = new boolean[SURFACE_RES_IDS.length];

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.multi_videos_layout);

        // create surface holders
        for (int i=0; i<mSurfaceViews.length; i++) {
            mSurfaceViews[i] = (SurfaceView) findViewById(SURFACE_RES_IDS[i]);
            mSurfaceHolders[i] = mSurfaceViews[i].getHolder();
            mSurfaceHolders[i].addCallback(this);
            mSurfaceHolders[i].setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }
    }

    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer player, int percent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer(" + indexOf(player) + "): onBufferingUpdate percent: " + percent);
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer(" + indexOf(player) + "): onCompletion called");
    }

    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer player, int width, int height) {
        Log.v(TAG, "MediaPlayer(" + indexOf(player) + "): onVideoSizeChanged called");
        if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
            return;
        }

        int index = indexOf(player);
        if (index == -1) return; // sanity check; should never happen
        mSizeKnown[index] = true;
        if (mVideoReady[index] && mSizeKnown[index]) {
            startVideoPlayback(player);
        }
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer(" + indexOf(player) + "): onPrepared called");

        int index = indexOf(player);
        if (index == -1) return; // sanity check; should never happen
        mVideoReady[index] = true;
        if (mVideoReady[index] && mSizeKnown[index]) {
            startVideoPlayback(player);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int i, int j, int k) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SurfaceHolder(" + indexOf(holder) + "): surfaceChanged called");
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SurfaceHolder(" + indexOf(holder) + "): surfaceDestroyed called");
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SurfaceHolder(" + indexOf(holder) + "): surfaceCreated called");

        int index = indexOf(holder);
        if (index == -1) return; // sanity check; should never happen
        try { 
            mMediaPlayers[index] = new MediaPlayer();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("sample.3gp");
            mMediaPlayers[index].setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); 
            mMediaPlayers[index].setDisplay(mSurfaceHolders[index]);
            mMediaPlayers[index].prepare();
            mMediaPlayers[index].setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayers[index].setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayers[index].setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayers[index].setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayers[index].setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    @Override protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaPlayers();
    }

    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMediaPlayers();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayers() {
        for (int i=0; i<mMediaPlayers.length; i++) {
            if (mMediaPlayers[i] != null) {
                mMediaPlayers[i].release();
                mMediaPlayers[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }


    private void startVideoPlayback(MediaPlayer player) {
        Log.v(TAG, "MediaPlayer(" + indexOf(player) + "): startVideoPlayback");
        player.start();
    }

    private int indexOf(MediaPlayer player) {
        for (int i=0; i<mMediaPlayers.length; i++) if (mMediaPlayers[i] == player) return i;
        return -1;  
    }

    private int indexOf(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        for (int i=0; i<mSurfaceHolders.length; i++) if (mSurfaceHolders[i] == holder) return i;
        return -1;  
    }
}
```

**R.layout.multi_videos_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/video_1_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/video_2_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/video_3_surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Fragment-based implementation:**

```
public class MultipleVideoPlayFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayer";

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.multi_videos_activity_layout);
    }

    public static class VideoFragment extends Fragment implements
        OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
        private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
        private boolean mSizeKnown;
        private boolean mVideoReady;

        @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.multi_videos_fragment_layout, container, false);
        }

        @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) getView().findViewById(R.id.video_surfaceview);
            mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
            mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer player, int percent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent: " + percent);
        }

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
        }

        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer player, int width, int height) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
            if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
                return;
            }

            mSizeKnown = true;
            if (mVideoReady && mSizeKnown) {
                startVideoPlayback();
            }
        }

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");

            mVideoReady = true;
            if (mVideoReady && mSizeKnown) {
                startVideoPlayback();
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int i, int j, int k) {
            Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");

            try { 
                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("sample.3gp");
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); 
                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        @Override public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }

        @Override public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }

        private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.release();
                mMediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }

        private void startVideoPlayback() {
            Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

**R.layout.multi_videos_activity_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment class="mh.so.video.MultipleVideoPlayFragmentActivity$VideoFragment"
        android:id="@+id/video_1_fragment" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment class="mh.so.video.MultipleVideoPlayFragmentActivity$VideoFragment"
        android:id="@+id/video_2_fragment" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment class="mh.so.video.MultipleVideoPlayFragmentActivity$VideoFragment"
        android:id="@+id/video_3_fragment" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**R.layout.multi_videos_fragment_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/video_surfaceview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

---

**Update:** Although it's been around for a while now, I just thought it'd be worth pointing out that Google's [Grafika project](https://github.com/google/grafika/) showcases a ['double decode'](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/DoubleDecodeActivity.java) feature, which *"Decodes two video streams simultaneously to two TextureViews.".* Not sure how well it scales to more than two video files, but nevertheless relevant for the original question.

Comment: Have you tried on Galaxy S-II v2.3.3. I'm getting problem that I'd mentioned above. Can you give an official documentation that if it depends upon device or kernel version.

Comment: @SuvamRoy: No, sorry, I do not have a Galaxy SII to test on. I can only provide you my emperical analysis described above. As different emulators do not seem to suffer the issue you describe, I'm pretty sure the limitation is not related to the software. Running above code on my Galaxy Nexus works perfectly fine. If the exact same code doesn't on your Galaxy SII, then my hypothesis is that it's simply device dependent, until proven wrong.

Comment: all work fine using local file, I have problems using stream rtsp instead. Second video get MediaPlayer error (1,1)

Comment: @MH. The same code instated of LinearLayout If I used scrolling view it's not working !

Comment: FWIW, there's a reported upper bound now from the `getMaxSupportedInstances()` method (API 23): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#getMaxSupportedInstances()

Comment: @MH. Is there any update? As currently, I am developing one application where I have to play more than one video simultaneously. In some devices in running properly. And in some devices, it only plays a single video. I am using exoplayer in my case. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Chk out this code, It works....

```
video1=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
    video1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getPackageName()+ "/"+R.raw.sample));
    video1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    video1.requestFocus();
video2=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideview);
video2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getPackageName()+ "/"+R.raw.sample1));
video2.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
video2.requestFocus();

Thread view1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DISPLAY);
        video1.start();
    }
});

Thread view2=new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DISPLAY);
        video2.start();
    }
});
```

But it is depending upon ur device h/w weather it support multi `video-view` or not. If its not supporting it will give you error as `This video can not be played Error (1, -110)`

Comment: I have an issue with this implementation. The videos do not display the full width for some reason. Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder: It is taken care by `VideoView` to display height or width of video to maintain aspect ratio. It is purely based on your video resolution and device resolution and space provided to `View`.
 But still you want to make it full width, put your View inside `RelativeLayout` and define `alignParentRight=true` and `alignParentLeft=true` to your `View`. But this will not maintain your aspect ratio of Video

Answer (score 0):

You aren't giving any code examples.

From my experience I've found that you can do this with Fragments (at least on the devices I've used). Remember there's a Fragment support library for older devices.

So basically put a LinearLayout or something in place of the VideoViews, then use Fragment transactions to replace the LinearLayouts with a Fragment that has a VideoView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class CustomPictureActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
VideoView vd1,vd2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    vd1=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.v1);
    vd2=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.v2);
    vd1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/file.mp4"));
    vd1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    vd1.requestFocus();
    vd1.start();

    vd2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/android.mp4"));
    vd2.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    vd2.requestFocus();
    vd2.start();
}
```

}

and xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<VideoView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" 
    android:id="@+id/v1"/>

<VideoView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" 
    android:id="@+id/v2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Code implementation is too much easy dude I know that, but Samsung Galaxy S-II doesn't support this. This code works file on Samsung Galaxy Tab(Honey comb), but not in Galaxy S-II.

Comment: Ok..But Can you tell me necessarily of using it?as playing two video is not justifiable which sound will you listen

Comment: Actually my target is to create a video conferencing call application and I'm able to do it on Galaxy Tab(version 3.1). But I failed to do support it on Galaxy S-II(version 2.3.3). When I'm going to play multiple video on Galaxy S-II, it gives native error. Sound is not my problem, I can handle it. Just to do support to play video it on Galaxy S-II.