# Backport stagefright and NuPlayer to Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer

My requirement is to be able to play a live video stream in my Android app. The stream will be over RTSP/RTP. I have no control over the source; and it looks like the RTP payload does not meet the requirements outlined in the Developers Guide [Video encoding recommendations](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations). Specifically, the following requirement seems to be violated by the video source:

> For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the moov atom must precede any mdat atoms, but must succeed the ftyp atom

Basically, it looks like we get raw H264 data (not wrapped in a container).

Now,

1. I was not able to play this stream using the `MediaPlayer` class on an Android 2.2 Samsung Galaxy Tab.
2. However, I was able to play it on an Android 2.3 Samsung Galaxy S.
3. Some third-party apps (MX Player) were able to play the same stream on the 2.2 Galaxy Tab as well.

In both cases 2 and 3 above, the DDMS logs pointed to the fact that Stage Fright framework was being used internally, while in case 1, PVP (i.e, OpenCore) was being used. All this leads me to conclude that:

1. My stream cannot be played by OpenCore framework.
2. My stream can be played using Stagefright - even on Android 2.2

Which brings me to my question:

> What does porting stagefright to Android 2.2 involve?

Further, I noticed in the AOSP source that the newer `NuPlayer` is responsible for playing RTSP streams now. Question:

> 1. Is it possible at all to port `NuPlayer` back to older versions of Android (2.2 or 2.3)?
> 2. If so, what do I need to do to be able to use it in my app?

I am aware that I can check out the sources and use NDK to build stagefright and NuPlayer (although I have never worked at the NDK level). What I don't know is how my app can then use this NuPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck similar problem, but I've found one solution. You have to patch system build.prob file. Please have a look my question and also I posted my [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834882/how-to-play-multiple-video-files-simultaneously-in-one-layout-side-by-side-in-di)

By default stagefright is kept disable in build.prop file. You have to enable it and reboot your device. Then you can access stagefright framework which does support your requirements.

For RTSP streaming download live555MediaServer.exe file in your remote mechine and keep some media file in same location. Open live555MediaServer.exe file.

Use the following code -

```
private final String RTSP_FILE = "rtsp://<remote machine IP>/<file name>";

mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(RTSP_FILE));
```

Comment: This may work, but unfortunately it does not address my use case. I am developing an app which should play an RTSP stream. I cannot ask all users of my app to go through the entire process of editing a build.prop file after installing it. I am looking for a way to be able to do this without user intervention.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for me either. I don't have control over the remote server. Plus, the remote "server" happens to be an embedded chip.

Comment: I already did it in my office machine, and my app was running well without having any problem, all machines are connected with server. If you don't have any RTSP server, how can it generate this streaming. The live555MediaServer.exe file acts as a RTSP streaming server. If your machine is connected with server and if you have wi-fi connection or other else, you can run live555MediaServer.exe file in your machine.

Comment: Yes -we need to have RTSP "server" to generate the stream - but you seem to have a few invalid assumptions here. Server doesn't have to be a full-fledged server running a complete OS. It could be for example - an Android or iOS phone which acts as an RTSP server. Not all platforms have an implementation of live555MediaServer.

Comment: Secondly, I am not at liberty to discuss this in more detail - but our server is an embedded chip and it cannot be configured to use live555MediaServer.