# Building/finding shared libraries from Android source code

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, rtp

I wish to back port the Android RTP APIs introduced in version 3.1(Honeycomb) to earlier versions. I downloaded the source of version 4.0 and found that it these APIs had both java and native code. In order to build the native code with the NDK, certain shared libraries are required. 
According the Android.mk file, these are `libnativehelper`, `libcutils`, `libutils`, and `libmedia`. Though the source of all of these are present in the source code, building them was difficult. Each required many other shared libraries. For eg, `libmedia` requires these shared libraries: `libui`, `libcutils`, `libutils`, `libbinder`, `libsonivox`, `libicuuc`, `libexpat`, `libcamera_client`, `libstagefright_foundation`, `libgui` and  `libdl`.
So my question is, is there some way of obtaining the original 4 shared libs? Does it involve building the entire source?

Comment: I suppose the easiest way is to add your backported code to the build path of earlier version source and build entire one. It would take you 1-2 hours at most.

Comment: I was looking for something on similar lines. I asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10297244/570930) on SO, but did not get much info.

Comment: @AndreyErmakov, could you elaborate on that? Since I want to create shared libraries of some of the Android source code, do I build the entire source? Will this yield the shared libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say I need to build a piece of native code which is going to use standard Android shared libraries such as `libutils`, `libcutlis`, `libmedia`. I would perform following steps:

1. Install `AOSP` repository with target version.
2. Add my source code to appropriate directories under `./frameworks/base`. 
   In your case it might be easier to create a separate folder and put proper `Android.mk` of course.
3. You might get compile errors if required functions from those standard shared libraries are not present in the previous version.
4. When you build the code as part of `AOSP` it will build required libraries and link them for you automatically.

P.S. To accomplish that you're better to use a Linux-based build host.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and tell you how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

using cygwin terminal, build native part i.e. jni folder. To build using cygwin, goto jni folder using cygdrive command. Then type ndk-build. After successful completion, shared libraries i.e. .so files will be created in libs folder.

Comment: ndk-build of the code requires certain shared libraries which I don't have. My question is how to generate them.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your problem, you can pull the libraries from /system/lib of device or emulator. But you need a system permission. But you can do it by installing application.
Otherwise build your source code on linux platfor. Building process is very easy, just using 2 or 3 command. First time it is needed long time to build. After that you need very short time to build, it will build only according to the timestamp of modified code.
[Please have a look here](http://source.android.com/source/building.html)