# Multiple Videos in One Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, video

First I want to thank everybody for their tips. I want to build an activity with multi videos in the same activity. How can I do that? If there is a way to have it in a list view format where all the videos are displayed nicely and I can just chose any of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016906/how-to-play-multiple-video-in-different-video-view-in-one-activity

Answer (score 1):

```
try something like this:

    public class Two_videos extends Activity 
{
VideoView video1, video2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.two_video);

VideoView video1= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video1);
              video1.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/IOU.mp4");
            video1.start();

VideoView video2= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video2);
        video2.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/Movies/IMGmp4");
        video2.start();
   }
}
```

Create an activity called Two_videos and paste the above code.
In the layout two video.xml, create two video view with ids video1 and video2.