# Playing multiple video streams simultaneously in single layout using vitamio

Tags: android, video-streaming, vitamio

I am trying to play 2 video streams in a single layout using vitamio MediaPlayer. I used  example code specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834882/how-to-play-multiple-video-files-simultaneously-in-one-layout-side-by-side-in-di), activity based solution. I replaced the android MediaPlayer with vitamio MediaPlayer in the code because android is not supporting my stream. Now with vitamio MediaPlayer both the video streams are playing on the same surface (second one) and first surface is empty.

Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Have you tried the demo for Vitamio https://github.com/yixia/VitamioDemo

Comment: Add images and links to question, will help you get more community attention.

Comment: @coding crow, I did tried Vitamio Demo code. Still the same behavior. It seems another person also faced the same problem (https://bbs.vitamio.org/topics/343?locale=en)

Comment: Ok, then it is known bug. It should be taken care off by Vitamio team, you can contact there support or open a request on Github.

Comment: with vitamio player this is not possible to play multiple instances of media player because of dependency of .so files