# MultiThreading, AsyncTask and UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, video

I am developing an app in which I am playing multiple videos at a time. Also performing some operations at same time.

Now I am successful in running 2 videos at a time using `VideoView` by having reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834882/how-to-play-multiple-video-files-simultaneously-in-one-layout-side-by-side-in-di/20370974#20370974) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834882/how-to-play-multiple-video-files-simultaneously-in-one-layout-side-by-side-in-di/10188890#10188890).

Both options are working fine for me. But my question is, is it safe to play 2 videos at a time on UI thread or shall I go with option creating threads and playing them separately or shall I use `AsyncTask` or is it safe to use UI thread directly?? And please tell me the difference of using all 3 approaches.

Answer (score 1):

when you play a video it does decoding, buffering in background. It doesn't do this work on UI thread. You probably only need to call start() function on UI thread.

Comment: So you mean to say when we call `VideoView.start()` method, it implicitly runs on background??