# Multiple VideoViews in Single Activity

Tags: android, android-videoview

What i'm actually trying to make is a simple video player that plays a video "Side by Side"(for Virtual Reality Cardboards). I've used two VideoViews to accomplish this. But the problem is, there is a slight noticeable difference in the playback i.e; one of them plays first and then the other and same thing happens with the audio. I just want to do this with VideoView. Here is my code.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoL"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoR"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mycompany.mycb;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.net.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    VideoView vidL;
    VideoView vidR;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        vidL = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoL);
        vidR = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoR);
        String urlpath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myvideo;
        vidL.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
        vidL.start();
        vidR.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
        vidR.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am completely new to Android development sir. How to start a new thread?

Comment: refer [To this SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834882/how-to-play-multiple-video-files-simultaneously-in-one-layout-side-by-side-in-di/10161316#10161316)

Comment: @ShahidRoshan:Use two threads to play the two video at a time.But it depends on your h/w that it will support multi vide or not.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. "requestFocus();" solved the problem.

```
vidL.requestFocus();
vidR.requestFocus();
```

Complete working code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mycompany.mycb;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.net.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    VideoView vidL;
    VideoView vidR;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        vidL = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoL);
        vidR = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoR);
        String urlpath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myvideo;
        vidL.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
        vidL.requestFocus();
        vidL.start();
        vidR.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
        vidR.requestFocus();
        vidR.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this kind of solution. Play both videos only when both are prepared. This be very helpful if you want to play remote videos.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private VideoView vidL;
private VideoView vidR;

private boolean vidRPrepared;
private boolean vidLPrepared;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    vidL = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoL);
    vidR = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoR);
    String urlpath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myvideo;
    vidL.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
    vidR.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
    vidL.requestFocus();
    vidR.requestFocus();
    initRVideoView();
    initLVideoView();
}

private void initRVideoView() {
    vidL.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            vidRPrepared = true;
            startPlaying();
        }
    });
}

private void initLVideoView() {
    vidR.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            vidLPrepared = true;
            startPlaying();
        }
    });
}

private void startPlaying() {
    if(vidRPrepared && vidLPrepared) {
        vidL.start();
        vidR.start();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have answered my own question but my solution is not working now! Your answer helped but still the problem persists. There's still a slight problem in playback. Is there any way to mute one of the VideoView?

Comment: If you want to mute the sound, add the following method in one of the onPrepared methods, mediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);