# placing one video view over another video view in android is possible?

Tags: android, video

[image]My question is, in android one video view should play the video in entire screen and another video view should play another video in small size at the corner of the screen.
For this it requires two video views playing video at same time one over the another. is it possible to achieve in android ?

As i saw we can play two videos at same time in below link. But here two video views are not getting overlapped.
[How to play multiple video files simultaneously in one layout side by side in different view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834882/how-to-play-multiple-video-files-simultaneously-in-one-layout-side-by-side-in-di/10161316#10161316)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to play multiple videos at same time. You can use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout to place VideoView's.

Sample Source Code (Sample uses video file from asset folder)

activity_video_player.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<VideoView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/videoview2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"/>

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

VideoPlayerActivity.java

```
package com.mobiactivation.pop.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.mobiactivation.pop.R;


public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{

    VideoView mVideoView = null;
    VideoView mVideoView2 = null;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder2;
    protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_888);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview2);
        surfaceHolder = mVideoView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        surfaceHolder2 = mVideoView2.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder2.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        surfaceHolder2.addCallback(this);

        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "VIDEO");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        if (holder == surfaceHolder)
            play(getIntent().getStringExtra("path"));
        else
            play2(getIntent().getStringExtra("path"));
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mWakeLock.release();
    }

    void play(String name)
    {

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try
        {
            afd = getAssets().openFd(name);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
                {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            this.mWakeLock.acquire();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void play2(String name)
    {

        mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer2.setDisplay(surfaceHolder2);
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try
        {
            afd = getAssets().openFd(name);
            mediaPlayer2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mediaPlayer2.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
                {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            this.mWakeLock.acquire();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. I can able to play two video views at same time. But when i place one video view over another only the first video view is in focus and second one is not in focus.

Comment: What is mean by "focus" exactly? Share your layout file and post screenshot if possible

Comment: Added screenshot of what i am expecting.

Comment: What is mean by "focus" exactly? Share your layout file?

Comment: Focus means the first video view alone visible while playing video and the second video view is not visible.

Comment: From your screenshot i noticed that you are trying to play same video file with two diff VideoView's. I am not sure but this could be the issue. Please try playing two different files on two diff VideoView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84646/discussion-between-amit-padekar-and-praveen).

Comment: Where you able to achieve this? If yes, can you please share the solution.