# Inside scroll views ( ScrollView / RecyclerView / ListView ) videos are not playing.

Tags: android, video, scroll, android-videoview, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display Images and Videos in my App. For that I am using `RecyclerView`. Images are displaying but Videos are not displaying. The video completely downloading but it's not going inside `OnPreparedListener` in `VideoView`. If I am using only `VideoView` the video is playing .... Please suggest some solution.... Thank you. ( If anyone want to see the code I will post )

I used `TextureView` and `SurfaceView` also, I am getting same problem with these views too...

**This is the sample example with `scrollView` and `VideoView`**.

```
str = "http://files.parsetfss.com/13e1c98b-895f-401e-83f3-7bf9b944001d/tfss-e199dd99-2564-4092-9df8-4b279ca2e7d0-video.mp4";

Ion.with(context)
            .load(str)
            .progress(new ProgressCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {
                    System.out.println("" + downloaded + " / " + total);
                    Log.d("TAG", downloaded + " / " + total);
                }
            })
            .write(fileCache.getFile(str))
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<File>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, File file) {
                    // download done...
                    Log.d("TAG", file.getAbsolutePath());
                    // do stuff with the File or error
                    videoUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                    videoView2.setVideoURI(videoUri);
                    videoView2.requestFocus();
                    videoView2.setOnPreparedListener
                            (new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                                     Log.d("TAG", " mp4 Done ready to play ");
                                     videoView2.start();
                                     mp.setLooping(true);
                                     mp.setVolume(0, 0);
                                     videoView2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                             Log.d("TAG", " Volume ");
                                             if (abc) {
                                                 mp.setVolume(0, 0);
                                                 Log.d("TAG", " Volume 0 ");
                                                 abc = false;
                                             } else {
                                                 mp.setVolume(1, 1);
                                                 Log.d("TAG", " Volume 1 ");
                                                 abc = true;
                                             }
                                             return false;
                                         }
                                     });

                                 }
                             }

                            );
                }
            });


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="blpacademy.videotestwithscrollandwithout.VideoView_with_scroll">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />


   </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
```

**Update:**

I tried with `ListView` with `VideoView` too.... it is also not working ....

What I am thinking inside scroll views ( `ListView` / `RecyclerView` / `ScrollView` ) the video ( `VideoView` ) is not playing  .... If playing ( `TextureView` / `SurfaceView` ) the view is not scrolling...

Comment: You might want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10161316/295004 and the DoubleDecode activity of Grafika https://github.com/google/grafika/

Comment: Hi, @MorrisonChang I checked the answer, That was working but in my case inside any scroll view the videos are not playing.... any idea 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all my experiments I got to know that inside any scroll views ( `ListView` / `RecyclerView` / `ScrollView` ) if you want to play video ( `videoView` / `TextureView` / `SurfaceView` ) then you can't use `wrap_content` or `match_parent` for width & height. You have to assign static or dynamic values to the video. Then the video will work on scrolling views.

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
 />
```

Comment: I didn't get U, example for what ?

Comment: In scrolling view the videos can't play with wrap_content or match_parent. At this time we have to give static values to Height & Width for videoView,

Answer (score 0):

VideoView inside ScrollView with height/width wrap-content or match-content will give you unexpected results. It will not get height and width properly.

**Solution:**
Either you provide a fixed number for the height and width in the layout XML like this:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
 />
```

Or set the height and width to videoView at runtime like this:

```
videoView.setDimension(256,256);
```