# Android Media Player Multiple instances

Tags: android

I want to create a multiple instances of media player in android. Is anyone tried to do this?

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer1,mMediaPlayer2,mMediaPlayer3;

mMediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer2= new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer3= new MediaPlayer();
```

Comment: Have you tried this? What problem are you having?

Comment: Using a loop? Or create a method which creates an Object for you.

Comment: You can use loop to create multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely you can but y do need this as it may lead you to not able to manage your media properly. You may need to pay extra attention in releasing resources.

[try this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834882/how-to-play-multiple-video-files-simultaneously-in-one-layout-side-by-side-in-di/20370974#20370974)

Comment: I want to play simultaneous videos together.