# VideoView turn into black screen

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

**I am developing multi player video app, so in that i created 9 views 3*3.**

when i initialize all (3*3) videoview then working properly for few seconds and after some time video is goes to black screen, not show single video, **i am not understand this issue is device oriented or android not supports more than 1 video in activity**, anyone know how to resolve this issue, otherwise if video is turn into black then how to identify video is turned into black screen, if we found this then i will refresh view and again start video, i don't know it is correct way or not.

please anyone know about how to resolve this issue then please share information !

i use below code for show multiple video view in one activity

```
videoPlayer.setVideoPath("path");
videoPlayer.start();
videoPlayer.requestFocus();
videoPlayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);
```

**set prepare listener**

```
videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
 @Override
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
 }
```

**set completion listener**

```
 videoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
 @Override
 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
  //play next
  }
});
```

**handle error listener**

```
videoPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                // play next
                return true;
            }
        });
```

> when video play next before that i set some propertied to `mediaplyer` object

```
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(null);
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(videoPlayer.getHolder());
```

**i share basic code of my project, please tell me if anything is missing from me or android is not supported multiple videos in same activity.**

Comment: do you have any code inside onCompletion, you could add the lines of code that you have `mediaPlayer.setDisplay(null);
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(videoPlayer.getHolder());`, inside that listener. Let me know if it works

Comment: I added this lines but not working. If i play more than 2 video then , then 1st video is play and when second video will play then both view turn on to black

Comment: are you using all the 9 views with the same mediaPlayer instance?

Comment: No i am using different, different videoview instance

Comment: Then is 9 videoviews, so when media is prepared i got media player instance

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10161316/5052976

Comment: I checked,but its not working

Comment: are the videos are streamed from internet?

Comment: I recomend you to use ExoPlayer instead of MediaPlayer, since ExoPlayer has more compatibility with respect of video formats, also it´s more supported, I would recomend you to check the ExoPlayer video from Google IO 2016, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOzOZ7hRr00

Comment: i checked, with exoplayer but exoplayer also not supported.