# One media controller for two video views android

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I am trying to play two video views using the same media controller but it seems impossible to play them and stop them and seek through both at the same time 
can someone suggest a solution here is what I am trying :

```
//2 video views 

videoview=(VideoView)findviewbyid(R.id.videowview);
videoviewtwo=(VideoView)findviewbyid(R.id.videowview2);

//the media controller

 MediaController mc =new MediaController(this);

//setting uri for both:

videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
videoviewtwo.setVideoURI(uri1);

//setting same media controller object for both
 videoview.setMediaController(mc);
 videoviewtwo.setMediaController(mc);

//finally start both

 videoview.Start();
 videoviewtwo.Start();
```

after this both play well at the first time but when I try to repeat only one starts the other doesnt, thank you for your help.

Edit: I want them both to play at the same time each time I repeat the process .

Answer (score 0):

You need to release and set the mediaplayer to null before you can start the new video. Try to call this when the video has stopped and before you start a new video so you know that the mediaplayer is not busy.

```
    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
}
```

So next is to find out when the mediaplayer have stopped playing your video. A hint: MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener

Comment: I am not using here a media player . do you mean media controller ?

Comment: I'm not sure what what code you are using, but are you using a MediaPlayer at all? The mediacontroller is just a controller for the MediaPlayer. You should really take a look at this page https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: I am using a video view why do I need a media player ?

Comment: Damn, im sorry. I have been doing a lot of work with audio the last day so MediaPlayer is everything that is inside my head right now. But you're right, your should be using a VideoView. Could you try to add "requestFocus()" before each video starts? Example videoview.requestFocus();

Comment: look let me explain the problem again , I want both videos to play at the same time using the same media controller but the problem is that only one video is responding when I click through the media controller the other doesnt , how I can control both at the same time is the question,thanks for your time.

Comment: Oh, you want them to play the same time. You should check out this post for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834882/how-to-play-multiple-video-files-simultaneously-in-one-layout-side-by-side-in-di/10161316#10161316