# How to display two Videoview in an Activity?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to display two video view in an activity which ui is like what's app video calling. When 1st video is loading another video do not start at a time only single video is playing. I want to play both videos at same time. And also want to swap video view place on click of those view like interchanging 1st video view with another.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834882/how-to-play-multiple-video-files-simultaneously-in-one-layout-side-by-side-in-di

Comment: @Ankita thanks for replay let me check